# How to create nested gridviews dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have to create nested gridviews where the a field in the parent gridview will decide how many level will be there.

For example if the parent gridview row is formed for a team lead,I have to make 1 child grid for developers.But  if the parent gridview corresponds to a manager,
the child gridview will be for team leader and the grandchild grid will be of developers.
similarly for senior manager,there will be 3 levels of hierarchy.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple work flow how to create nested datagridview.Kindly follow the steps and procedures in it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189997/Gridview-inside-Gridview-in-asp-net-Csharp

Following is the link of the video which might be helpful to you in this case

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LYyIZabghw&noredirect=1

Comment: Hi,I have prepared another gridview in similar fashion but this time I need to create the child,grand child,great grandchild and so on gridviews dynamically.How should I create the asp:template field in loop for to create as many heirarchies as the number of records.